# Is there a more concise way to alternate shape and background colour with Java in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

In Processing, I need the rectangle in the middle of the window appear as purple and the background yellow when the mouse is hovering within the rectangle. When the mouse is anywhere else on the screen (touching the background) the rectangle should be yellow and the background should be purple. I've achieved my goal, but am wondering if there's a more concise way to write this code, or if there are alternative approaches?

```
void setup ()
{
 size(500, 500);
}

void draw()
{
  background(205, 86, 219); // purple
  rectMode(CENTER);
  fill(231, 240, 111); // yellow
  rect(250, 250, 250, 200);
 if (mouseX >= 125 && mouseX <= 375 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 300)
 {
   background(231, 240, 111); // yellow
  fill(205, 86, 219); // purple
  rect(250, 250, 250, 200);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 [`color`](https://processing.org/reference/color_.html) objects with the 2 colors:

```java
color color1 = color(231, 240, 111); 
color color2 = color(205, 86, 219);
```

Set a `boolean` variable when the mouse is on the rectangle:

```java
boolean onRect = mouseX >= 125 && mouseX <= 375 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 300;
```

Use the [ternary (`?:`) operator](https://processing.org/reference/conditional.html) to select the color dependent on the state of `onRect`:

```java
background(onRect ? color1 : color2);
```

```java
fill(onRect ? color2 : color1);
```

---

Complete example:

```java
color color1 = color(231, 240, 111); 
color color2 = color(205, 86, 219); 

void setup () {
    size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
    boolean onRect = mouseX >= 125 && mouseX <= 375 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 300;
    background(onRect ? color1 : color2);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(onRect ? color2 : color1);
    rect(250, 250, 250, 200);
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @amac Thank you. You're welcome.